# Sliding Window Index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use-case where I am getting payment events. I need to provide a search engine on these events. Payment event has multiple attributes on which an aggregation search query can be run. For e.g. : count failed transaction for accountId : 123 when user was using deviceId : 123 in last 10 days.
This query will be fired in sync path so p95 latency expectation is 10ms. I am thinking of using ElasticSearch with mapping defined as follows :

```
{
  "accountHolder": String,
  "currency": String,
  "merchant": String,
  "device": String",
  "transactionType": String,
  "ip": IP,
  "os": String,
  "timestamp": Date,
  "transaction_amount" : Int,
  "status" : String 
}
```

Now maximum time window for a query can be 3 months i.e only last 3 months data needs to be searched. I am thinking of using rolling indexes but issue with rolling indices is it removes entire index data. For e.g : if index is on 3 months data then after 3 months entire last 3 months data goes away whereas I just want last 2 months and 29 day data to remain and only 1 day is deleted.

I know this can be achieved via `DeleteAPI` but that will be expensive query. Other option is to have index on day instead of month but then I need to perform aggregation across indices which is expensive.

Is there any other way to optimise this? And can I achieve p95 less than 10ms with ElasticSearch? And one last question, instead pushing event directly should I aggregate it with existing events to reduce aggregation load during read path?

Access patterns :
Write TPS : 1000
Read TPS : 10000

Thanks

Comment: Figured out how to make `rollover` behave like sliding window. We can use `alias` with `rollover` index to make sure that only last day is deleted instead of entire 3 month data. 
Ref : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-rollover-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve your problem without deleting data is to use [Roll ups](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-rollup.html) whose main objective is to pre-aggregate data for the desired duration for each desired field combination. So instead of searching on millions of documents for a given user/device combo, you'd only be searching on a single one that aggregates 3 months of data, or a few ones that aggregate shorter time intervals.

You could for instance aggregate daily data for each user/device pairs and then your query would only need to run on 90 daily documents for that user/device pair.

You should give it a look at the official documentation I linked above and also the [following article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-create-manage-and-visualize-elasticsearch-rollup-data-in-kibana) which explains how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks @Val ! This is what I need. It is marked as experimental as of now so would it be okay to use it in production. Also, query can come with any permutation of attributes but still with rollup I will be searching very less documents.
Given that over 3 months I will have around 1 Billion documents. I will do rollup each day which will bring the count in millions. With this volume is 10ms achievable or should I benchmark and find out.
And thanks again for your valuable comment.

Comment: I was able to test this out and it is working. Is it possible that i can generate multiple aggregated rollups on different combinations. For e.g : user and device, user and transaction_type, etc. This will further reduce the number of documents to scan during read path

Comment: Absolutely, you can define [as many rollup groups](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rollup-understanding-groups.html) as needed